# encode SignTypedDataV4 using encode_structured_data in python

Tags: web3.py, accounts, signature, eip712

### TL;DR

I am trying to use web3.py and eth_account to encode and sign a EIP-712 message with arrays and I am running into an error:
`KeyError: 'address'`

So, how can I encode this message?

### Context:

`encode_structured_data` throws `KeyError` when there is an array type in a struct. The error doesn't give any context and seems to support some array types (ex. `Person[]` doesnt seem to throw error but `address[]` throws error). When I simply just make the Person.wallets to be address instead of `address[]` it works (obviously I update the message accordingly). But for some reason, an array of address just is not working. For more context, I am trying to make it work with the SignTypedDataV4 on MetaMasks [test Dapp](https://metamask.github.io/test-dapp/).

The code I am using:

```py
msg = {
      'domain': {
        'chainId': 1,
        'name': 'Ether Mail',
        'verifyingContract': '0xCcCCccccCCCCcCCCCCCcCcCccCcCCCcCcccccccC',
        'version': '1',
      },
      'message': {
        'contents': 'Hello, Bob!',
        'from': {
          'name': 'Cow',
          'wallets': ['0xCD2a3d9F938E13CD947Ec05AbC7FE734Df8DD826',
                      '0xCD2a3d9F938E13CD947Ec05AbC7FE734Df8DD826'],
        },
        'to': [
          {
            'name': 'Bob',
            'wallets': ['0xCD2a3d9F938E13CD947Ec05AbC7FE734Df8DD826',
                        '0xCD2a3d9F938E13CD947Ec05AbC7FE734Df8DD826'],
          },
        ],
      },
      'primaryType': 'Mail',
      'types': {
        'EIP712Domain': [
          { 'name': 'name', 'type': 'string' },
          { 'name': 'version', 'type': 'string' },
          { 'name': 'chainId', 'type': 'uint256' },
          { 'name': 'verifyingContract', 'type': 'address' },
        ],
        'Group': [
          { 'name': 'name', 'type': 'string' },
          { 'name': 'members', 'type': 'Person[]' },
        ],
        'Mail': [
          { 'name': 'from', 'type': 'Person' },
          { 'name': 'to', 'type': 'Person[]' },
          { 'name': 'contents', 'type': 'string' },
        ],
        'Person': [
          { 'name': 'name', 'type': 'string' },
          { 'name': 'wallets', 'type': 'address[]' },
        ],
      },
    }
  
    new_msg = json.loads(json.dumps(msg), object_hook=_decode)
    new_msg['domain']['version'] = str(new_msg['domain']['version'])
    encoded_msg = encode_structured_data(new_msg)
    signed_msg = w3.eth.account.sign_message(encoded_msg, account)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please upgrade your eth-accounts library, this issue has been fixed in 0.7.0